# TYPO3 Custom File Name for rendered images

Tags: typo3, typo3-11.x

I wanted to ask if in TYPO3 LTS 11 is a way to change how TYPO3 generates the name for a rendered image?

In the template I use the f:image Viewhelper with cropVariant option to generates the image (done by TYPO3 Image Rendering).

```
<f:image image="{file}" cropVariant="desktop" />
```

That Image then has a name something like this: csm_my-image_88ade60319.jpg

Can I define how TYPO3 should name those rendered images?

For example to "my-image_large.jpg"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `cms_` part of the filename is hardcoded in the `TYPO3\CMS\Core\Resource\Processing\ImageCropScaleMaskTask::getTargetFileName` function. The hash at the end is added in the `TYPO3\CMS\Core\Resource\Processing\AbstractGraphicalTask::getTargetFileName` function. Not sure why `cms_` is added, but the hash is to make sure the file name is unique. The hash is generated using the file and configuration.

So by default it isn't possible. If you really want different file names you can [XCLASS](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/main/en-us/ApiOverview/Xclasses/Index.html) `TYPO3\CMS\Core\Resource\Processing\ImageCropScaleMaskTask` with something like:

```php
<?php
namespace Vendor\MyExtension\Resource\Processing;

class ImageCropScaleMaskTask extends \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Resource\Processing\ImageCropScaleMaskTask
{
    public function getTargetFileName()
    {
        $originalFileName = parent::getTargetFilename();
        $fancyFileName = ... // Do your things to change the file name
        return $fancyFileName;
    }
}
```

You'll probably also want to add something to configure what the file name should be. So you'd probably also need to XCLASS the `TYPO3\CMS\Fluid\ViewHelpers\ImageViewHelper` class or create a new ViewHelper to add some settings to the processing instructions.

Just make sure the file name is unique or you might get weird results.

Comment: `cms_` means likely that it's supposed to be shown in FE. there exist other prefixes too, like `preview_`, though they are perhaps not used on all systems very much.